# Call DocuSign RestApi using .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, docusignapi

I am looking to use the DocuSign [rest api](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/) in C# win forms.  I am using .Net 4.0. However  [DocuSign c# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/) does not support .NET 4.0.

Is there a sample code for RestApi using C# Winforms for DocuSign using .Net 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example which makes raw HTTP calls to the  DocuSign REST api using .Net 4.0. I am using the [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) class which is available in .net 4.0

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DocuSignDotNet40
{
  public partial class SignatureForm : Form
  {
    protected const string _username = ""; //Enter Username here
    protected const string _integratorKey = ""; //Enter Integrator Key here
    protected const string _password = ""; //Enter Password here
    protected const string _baseUri = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"; //Enter baseUri here
    protected const string _accountId = ""; //Enter acountId here
    protected string _authHeader = "";

    private void CreateEnvelope_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string requestUrl = _baseUri + "/v2/accounts/" + _accountId + "/envelopes";
      var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
      httpWebRequest.Method = "Post";
      httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
      httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", _authHeader);

      string jsonRequest = GetCreateEnvelopeJson();
      var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonRequest);
      using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
      {
          stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
      }
      var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
      {
          string responseJson = sr.ReadToEnd();
          // more stuff
      }
    }

    public string GetCreateEnvelopeJson()
    {
      return @"{
        'emailSubject': 'Please sign the agreement',
        'status': 'sent',
           'recipients': {
               'signers': [
                   {
                       'email': 'janedoe@acme.com',
                       'name': 'jane doe',
                       'recipientId': 1,
                       'tabs': {
                           'signHereTabs': [
                               {
                                   'documentId': '1',
                                   'pageNumber': '1',
                                   'xPosition': '80',
                                   'yPosition': '80',
                               }
                           ]
                       }
                   }
               ]
           },
           'documents': [
               {
                   'documentId': '1',
                   'name': 'Contract',
                   'fileExtension': 'txt',
                   'documentBase64': 'RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP'
               }
           ]
       }";
    }
    public void GetEnvelope()
    {
        string envelopeId = "";//Enter EnvelopeId here
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(envelopeId)) throw new ApplicationException("Invalid Envelope Id");

        string requestUrl = _baseUri + "/v2/accounts/" + _accountId +"/envelopes/" + envelopeId ;
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "Get";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", _authHeader);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string responseJson = sr.ReadToEnd();
            // more stuff
        }

    }

    public SignatureForm()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_username)) throw new ApplicationException("Invalid _username");
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_integratorKey)) throw new ApplicationException("Invalid _integratorKey");

      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_password)) throw new ApplicationException("Invalid _password");
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_baseUri)) throw new ApplicationException("Invalid _baseUri");
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_accountId)) throw new ApplicationException("Invalid _accountId");
      _authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + _username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + _password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + _integratorKey + "\"}";
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, can i get any sample code for getting docuSign tags(Sign Tag, Initials, Name with date etc)  in winforms C#.net(4.0)

Comment: Please post a new question with specific details. Include what you have done so that you will more likely get an answer. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page